# accessing network path and copy file to the system = c#

Tags: c#, networking

i want to create a small c# application. there is a text box  and a button in form. if anyone enter a network path for a file and press the button, then the application must copy that file to a folder within that system. How can i do this.?

How to access a network path and how can i copy the file in that path to the system??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Net work paths are accessed by there full UNC ie \Server\Share\drive\file.  As long as you have credentials to access them.  You can use [system.io.file.copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) to move the files.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the OpenFileDilog class in .net to browse through the files.

Also you can visit these links for Copy and other functionalities.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(VS.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28VS.71%29.aspx)